# Async mosquitto client trying to re-connect with mosquitto broker

Tags: asynchronous, background, client, mqtt, mosquitto

Trying to implement an asynchronous client based in mosquitto MQTT broker, running forever in the background. My purpose is create a client able to connect / reconnect to broker in case the broker becomes offline at some time. I expected all connection / reconnection logic was managed by mosquitto callbacks (event-driven). However, this code doesn't try to connect to broker in case you try to run the client when the broker is stopped (offline) at initial time:

```
struct mosquitto *broker;
char ip[INET_ADDRSTRLEN]; // broker ip address
int port; // 1883
int keepalive; // 60
bool running = true;


int main(void)
{
    mosquitto_lib_init();
    broker = mosquitto_new(NULL, true, NULL);

    mosquitto_connect_callback_set(broker, on_connect_callback);
    mosquitto_disconnect_callback_set(broker, on_disconnect_callback);
    mosquitto_message_callback_set(broker, on_message_callback);

    mosquitto_connect_async(broker, ip, port, keepalive);
    mosquitto_loop_start(broker);


    while(running) {
        pause();
    }
}
```

After some testing, replaced

```
mosquitto_connect_async(broker, ip, port, keepalive);
```

by a while loop polling for the first success returned by mosquitto_connect_async function:

```
bool connected_to_broker = false;
while (!connected_to_broker) {
    rc = mosquitto_connect_async(broker, ip, port, keepalive);
    if (rc == MOSQ_ERR_SUCCESS) {
        connected_to_broker = true;
    } else {
        sleep(retry_timeout);
    }
}
```

After the while loop, it seems all the source code can be based on mosquitto callbacks.

Is this the expected way to manage this situation? Or should be managed in a different way? Thanks!

Comment: Please share all the relevant code, especially the definition of your variables and callbacks. First you have a variable `broker` (what is in fact a client instance) and later you pass some other instance `cli_ctx.broker`

Comment: Sorry, I edited the relevant source dode. The content of callbacks is not relevant, is just a log to see if they are called.

Comment: If callbacks only output log messages, where is the reconnect logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to make multiple connection attempts. Your problem is that the first attempt fails for the same reason but does not yet fire any callbacks because the communication thread is not yet started.

If you check the return value of `mosquitto_connect_async` you will see it is  `MOSQ_ERR_ERRNO` with `errno` being set to `ECONNREFUSED` (111).

If `mosquitto_loop_start` is called before your first connection attempt, the disconnect callback should be fired - also with `rc == MOSQ_ERR_ERRNO` and `errno == ECONNREFUSED`

Comment: OMG. Thank you! I googled searching for examples, and in all of them, mosquitto_connect_async was called *before* mosquitto_loop_start. Just swapping the order as suggested, without using any while loop, makes the thing happen as expected. Thanks a lot for your answer, it was very really helpfull! :-)

Comment: Calling mosquitto_loop_start() before mosquitto_connect_async() was problematic for me - if you tried to connect again, it would not work - before I discovered this bug and upgraded to v2.0.13 (the bug is reportedly fixed in v2.0.12):

[link](https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/issues/2242)

Comment: Does this mean that `mosquitto_loop_start` has to be called before every `mosquitto_loop_async` just in case that `mosquitto_disconnect` actually stops the thread?